# How to display json value in browser?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

[image: console]

[image: output]

I snapped the value from my firebase database 
but i can only display [object] .
How can i display the value in browser?
I also want to ask if i can get a particular value from my console , for example the value in name or phone.

Comment: Try to use console.log(JSON.stringify(name));

Comment: Instead of putting pictures of code you should put the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Stringify the JSON object and then use it.